# How do I get a access token to make use of One Drive?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, onedrive

I am working for a while to get a access token to make use for in Open Drive but can't figure it out yet....

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const KEY = 'filled_in_key';

const OneDrivePicker = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load the OneDrive SDK asynchronously
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      // The OneDrive SDK is now loaded
      console.log('OneDrive SDK loaded');
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      // Cleanup script tag on component unmount
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);


  const handleCancel = () => console.log('CANCELLED');

  const handleSuccess = (files: any) => console.log('SUCCESS: ', files);

  const handleError = (err: any) => console.log('ERROR: ', err);


  const launchOneDrivePicker = () => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      const odOptions = {
        clientId: KEY,
        action: 'download',
        multiSelect: true,
        openInNewWindow: true,
        advanced: {
          endpointHint: 'api.onedrive.com',
          accessToken: 'I_NEED_THIS' // put here access token
        },
        success: (files: any) => {
          handleSuccess(files);
          resolve();
        },
        cancel: () => {
          handleCancel();
          reject();
        },
        error: (e: any) => {
          handleError(e);
          reject();
        },
      };

      if (OneDrive) {
        OneDrive.open(odOptions)
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={launchOneDrivePicker}>
      Click here
    </button>
  );
};
```

I have seen more people share the issue of not filling `endpointHint` causes the popup not go to the correct page: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1254 so making use of `endpointHint` looks almost required but I am still not sure how I get the right access token.

Someone who knows how to solve this?

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/open-file?view=odsp-graph-online#3-launch-the-file-picker